# My version of LD (w/ MinGW/msys2) came with a x64 copy. My PC can only run 32bit applications. Can I fix this with a pacman?

Tags: mingw, ld, msys2

I was having an issue compiling an app on my PC with GCC *or* G++. I didn't think this was normal, so I dug into the mingw64/bin folder, and when I went to ld.exe (since the main error was from there), I tried running it normally (just normal run like a normal app), and hey, hey! It's a x64 bit app. And, of course this has to happen on a **32 bit** PC. I know I installed the right MSYS2/MinGW because well, MinGW *and* MSYS2 wouldn't run. Is there a pacman -S command I can do to fix this issue? This is really affecting my coding and compiling. I tried reinstalling GCC and G++ just in case. Nope, it's a(n) LD.exe error. x64 app installed on a x32 PC for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a 32-bit computer, or just want to develop software that works on 32-bit computers, then you should use MSYS2's 32-bit GCC toolchain, which lives in `/mingw32`, not `/mingw64`.

Run this command to install the 32-bit toolchain:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-toolchain
```

Then make sure you start MSYS2 using the "MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit" shortcut or by running `mingw32.exe`.  This ensures the toolchain will be on your PATH so you can run it easily using the `gcc` or `g++` commands.  You should also run `which gcc` to check that you are using the right `gcc`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm reinstalling all the packages with MinGW32 (which also don't work with 32bit apps for some reason), and I'll get back as soon as possible.

Comment: You are being pretty vague.  If you edit your question with details about exactly what you did and what error messages you are seeing, then I might be able help.